# How to get an image library properties in a site and all its subsites in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have an image library in a site and its subsite and I want to access its properties using the SharePoint object model. I don't know how to achieve that using SharePoint Object Model. Here is the image of that Library[image]

Note here is the structure of my SharePoint sites and subsites. You can see the 'Images' Library in each of sites and subsite.
[image]

Comment: Kindly let me  know which property you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All these properties are available under SPList

```
  using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("spdev/";)) {
using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
 { 
    SPList list = oSPWeb.GetList("PublishingImages"); 
    list.EnableModeration = true;
    if (oSPWeb.Webs.Count > 0 ) 
    {
    recursivewebcheck(oSPweb);
    }
 } 

Void recursivewebcheck(SPWeb oSPweb)
{

    foreach (SPWeb web in oSPWeb.Webs)
        { 
            SPList list = web.GetList("PublishingImages"); 
            list.EnableModeration = true; web.Dispose(); 
            if (oSPWeb.Webs.Count > 0 ) 
            {
                recursivewebcheck(web);
            }
            web.dispose();
        }

}
```

Comment: I want to iterate through the site and subsites structure first! and then I can get the properties. Well, I want to access the content approval property. i want to set it to false.

Comment: Refer to this question i have answered a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344187/how-to-get-all-sites-and-sub-sites-in-sharepoint-and-access-an-image-library-list/4344547#4344547

Comment: It seems you had asked the same question previously as well do you need full code?

Comment: using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://spdev/"))                
     using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
     {
        SPList list = oSPWeb.GetList("PublishingImages");
        list.EnableModeration = true;
        foreach (SPWeb web in oSPWeb.Webs)
        {
             SPList list = web.GetList("PublishingImages");
             list.EnableModeration = true;
             web.Dispose(); 
                    }
                }