# Getting a list of all child Site-Columns

Tags: sharepoint, moss

In Sharepoint 2007, i have a custom site column. Lets call it X for now.

I have used it in diffrent places in my site and i now want to know which columns in my site are related to this X site-column.

is there anyway to get a list of all the lists using this site-column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to enhance the solution provide in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376732/how-to-get-an-image-library-properties-in-a-site-and-its-all-subsites-in-sharepoi/4376900#4376900) to rsolve your query

Comment: Sorry I can think of this as only solution

Comment: Brute force is probably the only method.